# Getting a Input type="image" value from a request.getParameter()

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Inside of my html, I have form that post back to my Servlet. I would like to get the value of my input type ="image" but instead I am receiving a null value.

My form:

```
 <form action="HomeController" method="post">
   <button type="submit" name="s4" value="someValue">
     <img src="s4.jpg" alt="phonestuff">
   </button>
   <input type="hidden" name="s4price" value="800">  
 </form>
```

my Servlet post:

```
double s4price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("s4price"));
String s4 = request.getParameter("s4");
System.out.println(s4price);
System.out.println(s4);
```

My output:

```
800.0
null
```

Expected output:

```
800.0
Note4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You submit button will not send any image value. Because **type="image"** *Defines an image as the submit button*

try this:-

```
<form action="HomeController" method="post">
 <button type="submit" name="s4" value="Note4">
    <img src="s4.jpg" alt="phonestuff">
 </button>
 <input type="hidden" name="s4price" value="800">  
</form>
```

OR: in order to send a the **s4** value you can send it as hidden field with a image submit button.

```
<form action="HomeController" method="post">
  <input type="image" src="s4.jpg" alt="Submit" >
  <input type="hidden" name="s4" value="Note4"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="s4price" value="800">  
</form>
```

servlet post:-

```
double s4price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("s4price"));
String s4 = request.getParameter("s4");
System.out.println(s4price);
System.out.println(s4);
```

output:

```
800.0
Note4
```

Comment: If it really works then would you please don't mind to accept the answer? welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Input type="image" does not pass on the value when you submit the form. You need to pass them in hidden value.